# How do I find the hour difference between two dates in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, date

I have two dates, formated like "Y-m-d H:i:s".  I need to compare these two dates and figure out the hour difference. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything? For example you could convert them both into unix timestamps (seconds) using `strtotime`, then subtract that, then divide by 3600 to get hours

Comment: Yes, I was dividing by 24 instead of 3600. doh!

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can convert them to timestamps and go from there:

```
$hourdiff = round((strtotime($time1) - strtotime($time2))/3600, 1);
```

Dividing by 3600 because there are 3600 seconds in one hour and using `round()` to avoid having a lot of decimal places.

Comment: Using `strtotime()` is **not the best way** managing dates. Consider using `\DateTime::createFromFormat($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s')->diff($dto2)` or similar functionality to work with dates (_+ we know the format we expect to parse_). It's almost 2015 outside, lets do thing the elegant way!

Comment: except that createFromFormat takes $format as the first parameter ;)
`\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->diff( $dto2 )`

Answer (score 34):

You can use [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class also -

```
$d1= new DateTime("06-08-2015 01:33:26pm"); // first date
$d2= new DateTime("06-07-2015 10:33:26am"); // second date
$interval= $d1->diff($d2); // get difference between two dates
echo ($interval->days * 24) + $interval->h; // convert days to hours and add hours from difference
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$seconds = strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1);
$hours = $seconds / 60 / 60;
```

Answer (score 7):

As an addition to accepted answer I would like to remind that [`\DateTime::diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) is available!

```
$f = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$d1 = \DateTime::createFromFormat($date1, $f);
$d2 = \DateTime::createFromFormat($date2, $f);

/**
 * @var \DateInterval $diff
 */
$diff = $d2->diff($d1);
$hours = $diff->h + ($diff->days * 24); // + ($diff->m > 30 ? 1 : 0) to be more precise
```

[`\DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props.h) documentation.

Answer (score 4):

### You can try this :

```
    $time1 = new DateTime('06:56:58');
    $time2 = new DateTime('15:35:00');
    $time_diff = $time1->diff($time2);
    echo $time_diff->h.' hours';
    echo $time_diff->i.' minutes';
    echo $time_diff->s.' seconds';
```

### Output:

8 hours 38 minutes 2 seconds

Answer (score 0):

```
$date1 = date_create('2016-12-12 09:00:00');

$date2 = date_create('2016-12-12 11:00:00');

$diff = date_diff($date1,$date2);

$hour = $diff->h;
```

Comment: This is not accurate as if there is more than 24h of difference, this could easily return 0 (ie. $diff->d = 1 and $diff->h = 0 )

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to parse your strings and do the difference between the two of them.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
$dayinpass = "2016-09-23 20:09:12";
$today = time();
$dayinpass= strtotime($dayinpass);
echo round(abs($today-$dayinpass)/60/60);
```