# Date is not formatting time correctly PHP

Tags: php

Hello I try to take the difference between two dates and display it.

My problem is that the time difference I get is not the correct one.

This is my code:

```
$time1 = strtotime('2014-03-28 15:20:00');
    $time2 = strtotime('2014-03-28 15:15:00');

    $diffTime = $time1 - $time2;

    echo date('H:i', $diffTime);
```

The result I get is:

```
02:05
```

The currect time should be this:

```
00:05
```

My guess that the date somehow takes timezone or something like this but Im not sure.

Thanks.

Comment: Recheck your result, [it works correctly](http://codepad.viper-7.com/KlEMif)

Comment: Maybe use `gmdate()` instead of `date()` as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172332/convert-seconds-to-hourminutesecond)

Comment: go through this link i hope this will be help 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763476/how-do-i-find-the-hour-difference-between-two-dates-in-php

Comment: @HieuLe it works by chance in your example. it's not actually doing what the OP is intending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/****************************************
$start_date = new DateTime('23:58:40'); *These two still give 
$end_date = new DateTime('00:00:00');   *a wrong answer
*****************************************/

$start_date = new DateTime('23:58:40');
$end_date = new DateTime('00:11:36');

$dd = date_diff($end_date, $start_date);

//Giving a wrong answer: Hours = 23, Minutes = 47, Seconds = 4 
echo "Hours = $dd->h, Minutes = $dd->i, Seconds = $dd->s";
```

Answer (score 1):

So what you're actually doing here is generating two UNIX timestamps (numbers) and then subtracting them. then you're passing the resulting number as if it were still a timestamp to `date()`.

essentially `$diffTime` is the number of seconds between your two times. you could divide by 60 to get minutes, and so on and so forth, but PHPs DateTime objects are much better.

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP docs:

https://www.php.net/strtotime

> Note:
> Using this function for mathematical operations is not advisable. It is better to use DateTime::add() and DateTime::sub() in PHP 5.3 and later, or DateTime::modify() in PHP 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$time1 = strtotime('2014-03-28 15:20:00');
$time2 = strtotime('2014-03-28 15:15:00');

echo round(abs($time1 - $time2) / 60,2). " minute"

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Below is the solution of date time in years,days.hours,minutes and seconds.

$time1 = strtotime('2014-03-28 15:20:00');
$time2 = strtotime('2014-03-28 15:15:00');

$diffTime = $time1 - $time2;

$y = ($diffTime/(60*60*24*365));
$d = ($diffTime/(60*60*24))%365;
$h = ($diffTime/(60*60))%24;
$m = ($diffTime/60)%60;
$s = ($diffTime)%60;


echo "Minutes - " .$m;
echo "<br/>";
```